# C# modulus operator

Tags: c#, modulus

I can write the program

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;

Console.WriteLine(a % b);
```

The answer I get is 3.  How does 3 mod 4 = 3???

I can't figure out how this is getting computed this way.

Comment: The result is correct. What were you expecting it to return?

Comment: You were thinking of b%a not a%b.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure what to expect, but I couldn't figure out how the remainder was 3.

Comment: Is it a modulus operator or a remainder operator? They differ when the divisor is negative. Specifically, both compute `r` in `D = dq + r`, but modulus rounds `d` towards minus infinity, while remainder rounds `d` towards zero.

Comment: zero 4s divide into 3 and remainder is 3

Comment: Modulo returns the remainder.  3 does not divide evenly (or without a remainder) into 4.  To state the obvious, you need at least 4.  Therefore, if you can make at least 1 whole division, then 3 remains.

Comment: Voting to close as per [What to do with "programming" Qs that are actually just basic arithmetic/ratio questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316914/5532169)

Comment: Modulus is the absolute value, Modulo is the remainder.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Because the remainder of 3 / 4 = 3.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator

Comment: That's very funny indeed.  However, you can extend the math problem by adding a decimal point to the top and more zeros to the dividend to get it to eventually go evenly which would equal .75 as a quotient and no remainder.  I didn't know the mod operator wouldn't do that, hence why I asked the question.

Comment: .75 is not a quotient. By definition the quotient is an integer.

Comment: Think only integers, not decimals

Comment: @Ben, `4` does not evenly go into `3` 0.75 times. That's sort of the point.

Comment: I was thinking decimals and I shouldn't have been.  Thank you all for your responses, they have been most helpful.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else that might be looking at this - if you allow for decimals you will never have a remainder, and the modulus operator is useless.

In this case, 3 / 4 = 0 r3

Comment: The modulus operator returns the NUMERATOR of the fraction that is left over after the division is done.

Answer (score 144):

> I wasn't quite sure what to expect,
>   but I couldn't figure out how the
>   remainder was 3.

So you have 3 cookies, and you want to *divide* them equally between 4 people.

Because there are more people than cookies, nobody gets a cookie (*quotient* = 0) and you've got a *remainder* of 3 cookies for yourself. :)

Comment: At which point the other three people jump you and take your cookies.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Leaving you with 0.  Now I get it!

Comment: This is often how I divide ice cream among my kids. Since there isn't enough for everybody to get some, I get the remainder.

Answer (score 19):

3 mod 4 is the remainder when 3 is divided by 4.

In this case, 4 goes into 3 zero times with a remainder of 3.

Answer (score 6):

I found the accepted answer confusing and misleading.

**Modulus** is NOT the same as modern division that returns a ratio of dividend and divisor. This is often expressed as a *decimal quotient* that includes the remainder in the quotient. That is what trips people up.

**Modulus is just the *remainder* in division before its used in a decimal quotient.**

Example: The division of two numbers is often expressed as a **decimal number** (quotient). But the result of the division of say, `1/3`, can also be expressed in whole numbers as "0 with a remainder of 1". But that form of quotient is not very helpful in modern math, so a decimal value or the **ratio** of the two numbers is often what we see returned in modern calculators.

```
1 / 3 = .333333333......
```

But modulus does not work that way. It ignores the *decimal quotient* value or ratio returned from division, takes the quotient expression of "0 with a remainder of 1" in `1/3`, and extracts the 1 or *remainder* that was returned from that division. It just strips out the remainder from the quotient and spits back the remainder of division **before** its converted to a decimal. Below is how modulus works...

```
1 % 3 = 1
```

As such, a better way of describing Modulus is to say it is what is *left over as an integer* (remainder) in the first number (dividend) after dividing the second number (divisor) into it as many times as possible.

```
1 % 1 = 0 because after dividing 1 into 1, one time, there's nothing left
2 % 1 = 0 because after dividing 1 into 2, two times, there's nothing left
1 % 2 = 1 because 2 won't go into 1, so 1 is left
```

These *whole number* remainders returned by **modulus** (modular math) are useful in software programs in extracting the day of a week, creating alternating sequences, finding if a number is even or odd, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I already think that the user may have understood the answers. Because there are so many good programmer.. in simple wording `%` tells you the reminder after dividing with your own integer.

e.g.

```
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int b = a % 2;
```

Now your input 13, it will give 1, because after diving 13 by 2 remainder is 1 in simple mathematics. Hope you got that.

Comment: Cheers for your explanation

Answer (score 2):

As explained by others, but if you don't want to use the "mod" operator. Here is the equation to figure out the remainder of "a" divided by "n"

`a-(n* int(a/n))`

Answer (score 0):

Another "as explained by others", but if you're curious about several more ways to do modulus (or use an alternative method), you can [read this article which benchmarks a few different ways](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/use-the-modulus-operator-or-alternative).

Basically, the fastest way is the good old fashioned modulus operator, similar to:

```
if (x % threshold == some_value)
{
    //do whatever you need to
}
```