# C#, one-dimension wrapping array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a one-dimensional array, and I need to run operations on it based on the adjacents cells of every cell.

For instance:

To run the operations on the first cell, I'll need to access the last cell and the second.

The second cell, I'll need to access the first cell and the third cell.

The last cell, I'll need to access the first cell and the one before the last cell.

My code so far is:

```
public static int[] firstRule(int[] numberArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numberArray[numberArray.Length - 1 - i] == numberArray[i] + 1 
            && numberArray[i + 1] == numberArray[i] + 1)
        {
            numberArray[i] = numberArray[i] - 1;
        }
    }
    return numberArray;
}
```

But the problem with my approach is that it would only work for the first cell, as it would take the last cell and the second cell correctly, but after that, everything would fall apart. I don't like posting without a lot of code but I have no clue how to follow this up.

I am trying to achieve the following:

Those values are numbers ranging from 0 to 3. If both the cell before and the cell after is the same number, I want to change it to x + 1
For instance: suppose I have 1 0 1 2 2. I would want to change 0 to 1. As the neighbor cells are both 0.

Comment: Those values are numbers ranging from 0 to 3. If both the cell before and the cell after is the same number, I want to change it to x + 1.

Comment: For instance: suppose I have 1 0 1 2 2. I would want to change 0 to 1. As the neighbor cells are both 0.

Comment: could you elaborate more on this, please? I actually think this is the better approach for the problem.

Comment: your for instance does't make sense as written, and the term you're looking for is 'element' of an array.  this smells like a problem work assignment..

Comment: what are you ultimately trying to achieve?.. a sort?

Answer (score 4):

Just keep it simple and use variables to calculate the left and right cell indices.  Inside your `for` loop you can do this...

```
var leftCell = i - 1;
if (leftCell < 0)
{
    leftCell = numberArray.Length - 1; // Wrap around to the end...
}

var rightCell = i + 1;
if (rightCell > numberArray.Length - 1)
{
    rightCell = 0;  // Wrap back around to the beginning...
}


// Now you can update your original code to use these computed indices...
if (numberArray[leftCell] == numberArray[i] + 1 
    && numberArray[rightCell] == numberArray[i] + 1)
{
    numberArray[i] = numberArray[i] - 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe I' missing something, but couldn't you refer to the left, current, and right simply by using the mod operator? That is,  prev:  (i-1) % arrayLength, current: i, next: (i+1)%arrayLength

Comment: @Tung (i-1 + arrayLength) % arrayLength is more accurate for the left index. Try i=0

Comment: @Seven, true C#'s % returns the remainder and not strictly "modulo".

Comment: hmm..  based on the question, the value of `numberArray[i]` shouldn't matter at all in determining whether it should be incremented, (let alone the value being increased).. `numberArray[Leftcell] == numberArray[Rightcell]` should be all that is needed,..  **but** I'm thinking the OP mistakenly forgot to specify it in his question..  Still, I would update this answer to include the loop, declaring the variables outside of the loop; the do a check, assignment vs this assignment, check, (conditional) assignment. pattern you have going here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
var len = numberArray.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    var leftIndex = (i - 1 + len) % len;
    var rightIndex = (i + 1) % len;

    // do your stuff with numberArray[leftIndex] and numberArray[rightIndex] 
}
```

`%` is [mod operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427602/c-sharp-modulus-operator). `% len` allows you to stay in range 0..len-1, so you can walk through array as if it has become 'cyclic'

Comment: ... what is the point of doing 2 mod operations on each iteration?.. to avoid doing two checks of each iteration? `i == 0 ? len - 1: i -1` `i == len ? 0 : i - 1`

Comment: @BrettCaswell just to keep it simple and the most readable. Not always the fastest solution is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments.

**Those values are numbers ranging from 0 to 3. If both the cell before and the cell after is the same number, I want to change it to x + 1

For instance: suppose I have 1 0 1 2 2. I would want to change 0 to 1. As the neighbor cells are both 0.**

I would create a new array, populate it with the values of the existing array and then change the values of the new array according to the results of the value in the existing array.

**Edit as Op is getting wrong values**
*I suspect you may not be copying the array correctly instead:*

```
Existing Array array // The array you are passing in as parameter.
```

Declare a new empty array:

```
int[] newArray;
int size = array.length;

for(int i =1; i<size-1;i++){

    if(array[i-1]==array[i+1])){
        newArray[i]=array[i]+1;
    }
    else{
        newArray[i]=array[i];
    }

}
if(array[size-1]==array[0]){
    newArray[size]= array[size]+1;
}
else{
        newArray[i]=array[i];
    }
if(array [size]==array[1]){
    newArray[0]= array[0]+1;
}
else{
        newArray[i]=array[i];
    }
```

*if there is a limit to the number and it reverts to zero after 2, then just do a simple `if` test for that.*

Comment: You are right @Heyyou. But I'm still getting index out of bounds in the third if. And I think you forgot an = sign inside the second if.

Comment: **As the neighbor cells are both 0.** there are NO neighbor cells that both `0`.. that's why it doesn't make sense

Comment: right, so you inferred that, by omitting the senseless part.. that was my point

Comment: I'm trying to get it to work. I'll update my original post with what I got so far.

Comment: @FilipeTeles, why are marking this answer as the solution if you can't get it to work?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work = ( Tried to change size to numberArray.Length-1 and stopped getting array out of bounds but the output is completely off.

Comment: @FilipeTeles, is 0 to 3 actually an index to another array?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void firstRule(int[] numberArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.Length; i++)
    {
        int? prevElement = i == 0 
            ? numberArray[numberArray.Length-1]
            : numberArray[i - 1];

        int? nextElement = i == numberArray.Length -1
            ? numberArray[0]
            : numberArray[i + 1];

        Console.WriteLine(
            String.Format("Prev: {0}; Current: {1}; Next: {2}",
                prevElement,
                numberArray[i],
                nextElement)
            );
    }
}
```

And then calling `firstRule(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 });` prints:

```
Prev: 3; Current: 1; Next: 2
Prev: 1; Current: 2; Next: 3
Prev: 2; Current: 3; Next: 1
```

Comment: This isn't wrapping around such that the previous element for i = 0 is 3, not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var triples = arr.Select((n, i) =>
{
    if (i == 0)
        return Tuple.Create(arr[arr.Length - 1], arr[0], arr[1]);
    else if (i == arr.Length - 1)
        return Tuple.Create(arr[i - 1], arr[i], arr[0]);
    else
        return Tuple.Create(arr[i - 1], arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
});

foreach (var triple in triples)
{
    Console.WriteLine(triple.Item1 + " " + triple.Item2 + " " + triple.Item3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### OPTION 1

assign regardless

```
    public static int[] firstRule(int[] numberArray)
    {
        int left,right;
        for (int i = 0, max = numberArray.Length - 1; i <= max; i++)
        {                
            left = (i == 0) ? max : i - 1; 
            right = (i == max) ? 0 : i + 1;

            numberArray[i] = (numberArray[left] == numberArray[right]) ? numberArray[i] + 1 : numberArray[i]; //always peforms an assignment;
        }
        return numberArray;
    }
```

#### OPTION 2

conditionally assign

```
    public static int[] secondRule(int[] numberArray)
    {
        int left,right;
        for (int i = 0, max = numberArray.Length - 1; i <= max; i++)
        {   
            left = (i == 0) ? max : i - 1; 
            right = (i == max) ? 0 : i + 1;

            if (numberArray[left] == numberArray[right])
            {
               numberArray[i]++;
            }
        }
        return numberArray;
    }
```

#### OPTION 3

left and right are only used 1 time in each iteration.. so why bother assigning them to a variable???...

```
    public static int[] thirdRule(int[] numberArray)
    {            
        for (int i = 0, max = numberArray.Length - 1; i <= max; i++)
        {                
            if (numberArray[(i == 0) ? max : i - 1] == numberArray[(i == max) ? 0 : i + 1])
            {
                numberArray[i]++; // what happens if numberArray[i] is 3, should it become 4 or 0?
            }
        }
        return numberArray;
    }
```

#### OPTION 4 (UNSAFE)

unsafe - fixed - pointers

```
    public static int[] fourthRule(int[] numberArray)
    {
        unsafe {
            int* pointer, right, left; 

            for (int i = 0, max = numberArray.Length - 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                fixed (int* p1 = &numberArray[0], p2 = &numberArray[i], p3 = &numberArray[max])
                {
                    pointer = p2;
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        left = p3;
                        right = pointer;
                        right++;
                    }
                    else if (i == max)
                    {
                        left = pointer;
                        left--;
                        right = p1;
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        left = pointer;
                        left--;
                        right = pointer;
                        right++;
                    }

                    if (*right == *left) {
                        *pointer = *pointer + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return numberArray;
    }
```

Comment: this assumes your `int[]` length is greater then 2

Answer (score 0):

Recently came up against this myself and found this to be a solid method.
`

```
int length = numberArray.Length; 
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    int iMinus = (((i - 1) % length) + length) % length;
    int iPlus = (((i + 1) % length) + length) % length;
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work. It determines the appropriate cells for the operation in each loop and executes the operation. You didn't state what that operation was so you need to fill in the DoYourOperation method.

```
public static int[] processArray(int[] numberArray)
{
    for (int i= 0; i < numberArray.Length; i++)
    {
        int firstCell;
        int secondCell;
        //Check if first cell
        if(i == 0)
        { 
            firstCell = numberArray[numberArray.length-1]; //Last cell
            secondCell = numberArray[i++]; //Next cell
        } 
        //Check if last cell
        else if(i == numberArray.Length - 1)
        { 
            firstCell = numberArray[i--]; //Cell before last one
            secondCell = numberArray[0]; //First cell
        }  
        else
        {
            firstCell = numberArray[i--];
            secondCell = numberArray[i++];
        }

        DoYourOperation(firstCell, secondCell);
    }  
}
```

Comment: You need to replace all the `i++` and `i--` calls within the loop to `i + 1` and `i - 1` because that will update the value of `i` and you don't even get the correct value returned (it returns `i` then increments or decrements).

Comment: Yes that's true although after reading the comments on the question it seems as I have misunderstood the question.