# Modulo Why does the console write 3?

Tags: c#

Why does this make sense? i want someone to explain it for dummies because i'm new to coding (Sorry in advance).

I'm trying to learn c# and i come across this code as a question.

```
int x = 15;
int y = 6:
x % = y;
Console.Writeline(x);
```

Console writes 3.

I was reading a comment someone left on the question and he said:

"15 / 6 = 2

6 * 2 = 12

15 - 12 = 3"

This might be so basic to so many of you and i probably sound like the biggest cuck on earth. But is that really how it's calculated?

Comment: yes he is right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# modulus operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427602/c-sharp-modulus-operator)

Comment: Can I ask how this is off topic? I'm new and I needed help. I asked a question(which was very basic) and I got an answer. I was happy with that, then someone put it on hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, % means modulo. It is the remainer after the division.

> 15 / 6 = 2*6 + 3

So 15 % 6 is 3 :)

Comment: Wow. That's so basic... Thankyou, your explanation helped

Comment: No problem :) You can then accept my answer, so others will also see that it is helpful and correct. It is the green check mark in the left.

Answer (score 0):

because `x % = y;` is expended to `x = x % y;` and % gives you remainder. So when you do 15 % 6 it will give you 3.